# What is wrong with this mod_rewrite redirect?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a simple redirect which I just can't get to work and I don't know what's wrong. The server's throwing me a 500 Internal Server Error for no reason I can understand.

I'm trying to achieve the following: if a user types the address `www.example.com`, it will actually be routed to `domain/` subdirectory in my server. So if user requests `www.example.com/index.htm`, it would fetch the file from `/var/www/html/domain/index.htm`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/$1 [L]
```

Mod_rewrite is enabled and functional, as this *does* work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/index.php?$1 [L]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `<VirtualHost *>ServerName www.domain.com DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain</VirtualHost>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to exclude the destination you want to redirect to:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteCond $1 !^domain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/$1 [L]
```

Otherwise you will get an infinite recursion since `domain/…` is also matched by `.*`.